# How to use argparse to grab command line arguments in Python?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to be able to save integer values after an option is passed through the command line. Ideally it would be:

```bsh
python thing.py -s 1 -p 0 1 2 3 -r/-w/-c
```

- `-s` - store the following integer
- `-p` - store the following integers

The final part can be only one of the three options (**-r**, **-w**, or **-c**), depending on what it is I need to do.

I've been trying to read tutorials but they all use the same two examples that don't explain how to store integers after a `-option`.

Comment: If the last part should be exactly one of three, you may want to make it a required positional argument, like commands in many other tools (e.g. `install` of `apt-get`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-s', type=int)
[...]
>>> parser.add_argument('-p', type=int, nargs='*')
[...]
>>> group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
>>> group.add_argument('-r', action='store_true')
[...]    
>>> group.add_argument('-w', action='store_true')
[...]    
>>> group.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')
[...]    
>>> parser.parse_args("-s 1 -p 0 1 2 3 -r".split())
Namespace(c=False, p=[0, 1, 2, 3], r=True, s=1, w=False)
```